# Devise-invitable : Upon inviting a user, 2 emails are being sent, an invitation mail and a mail that says "Thank you for registering with us"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, devise-invitable

I am using `Devise-invitable` to send invitations to users using their email addresses. When I send and invitation, one of the mails that is (correctly) sent is one with the invitation link. However, another email gets sent which tells the invitee "**Thank you for registering with us.**".

I cannot find why this is happening.

```
Ruby version : 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]
Rails version : 4.2.4
devise version : 3.5.10
devise_invitable version : 1.6.0
```

Code in invitations controller:

```
class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
 def create
  params[:user][:email].each do |email|
    User.invite!({:email => email}, current_user) #If I comment out this line, both emails are not sent
  end
  redirect_to root_path
 end
end
```

Code in User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# after_create :send_welcome_email
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:  
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :invitable, :omniauthable, :database_authenticatable,   :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable

attr_accessor :user_profile_phone, :user_profile_city

# Relationships
has_many :identities
has_many :orders
belongs_to :role, :dependent => :destroy
belongs_to :userdatum, :dependent => :destroy
belongs_to :userprofile, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :comments
has_many :deliveries
has_many :conversations, :dependent => :destroy

# Filters
before_save :assign_role  
after_create :send_welcome_mail

def send_welcome_mail
  UserMailer.registration(self).deliver_now
end

def assign_role
  self.role = Role.find_by name: "User" if self.role.nil?
end

def facebook
  identities.where( :provider => "facebook" ).first
end

def facebook_client
  @facebook_client ||= Facebook.client( access_token: facebook.accesstoken )
end

def google_oauth2
  identities.where( :provider => "google_oauth2" ).first
end

def google_oauth2_client
  if !@google_oauth2_client
    @google_oauth2_client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => 'Test', :application_version => "1.0.0" )
    @google_oauth2_client.authorization.update_token!({:access_token => google_oauth2.accesstoken, :refresh_token => google_oauth2.refreshtoken})
  end
  @google_oauth2_client
end

def admin?
  self.role.name == "Admin"
end

def sytlist?
  self.role.name == "Stylist"
end

def user?
  self.role.name == "User"
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending both emails yourself.

`User.invite!` sends out an invitation email by default.

You need to remove the `after_create :send_welcome_mail` in `user.rb`. That's what is sending out the "welcome email".

Answer (score 0):

Solution I used was to check for token here :

```
after_create :send_welcome_email

def send_welcome_mail
    if self.invitation_token.nil?
      UserMailer.registration(self).deliver_now
    end
end
```

and add

```
def accept_invitation!
    super
    UserMailer.registration(self).deliver_now
end
```

Not sure if this is the best but it solved my problem.